# Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found and other Class encrypter does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After adding aliases and the `laravelcollective/html` service provider, I'm getting an error.

Comment: Please show the entire error message

Comment: please explain more

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make changes to your core application configuration, don't forget to clear cache and dump autoload, since the application is often being served by the cache, so it does not pick up your changes. Use these commands to clear application cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
```

After this, reload your page, and everything should be up and running.